# How to export HTML form data to an excel file saved on a shared network drive?

Tags: html, excel

I want to make a form for office use. Office computers don't take scripts due to security restrictions. The HTML form will be used by multiple users to save data to a single excel file.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative... one I haven't needed to do in about 15 years, but maybe this will work for you...

Make a form in an Access DB.  You're all on the same network with a shared drive.  Access actually has protections for this exact sort of scenario.  You won't have to worry about overriding each others' data, and you can use the nice form designer.

Comment: We use Access DB currently, but it is too buggy. 
1. If I click Tab, it clears the form and goes back to the previous textbox. 
2. If I press enter to select an option from a dropdown, it submits the form. 
3. Very slow. 

This is why I was looking for an alternate form via HTML.

Comment: @HarshadPawale Sounds like you need to fix your form.  Access doesn't normally do that, and you can set a tab order and all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Google Forms**, it will collect/store data into a google-sheets that you can easily export/save-as MS Excel file.

This [Google tutorial](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/forms/get-started/) will guide you step-by-step to create the form.

Comment: Google-sheets is restricted on office computers due to PCI compliance.

Comment: @HarshadPawale You might want to read this:  https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/6056694?hl=en

Comment: Do you have access to an intranet server that you can put an app on? If yes, then you can deploy a `Drupal CMS` to handle the form collection, then you can build a query to export data into CSV that you can import into excel.